# ctime(&rawtime) wiping malloc'ed character array?

Tags: c, unix, memory-management

I've honestly no idea what is going on here but here is my explanation>

I malloc an array of strings for holding an array of filenames, no problem there.  I then move into a while loop where it keeps all the correct values until it hits this to print the time

```
time(&rawtime);
printf("It is now: %s\n\n",ctime(&rawtime));
```

Then my values are gone.  Can't find them anywhere, I seem to now have an empty array.

Here is the rest of the code

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{

  int i,j, directSize,start=0,flag=0, menu;
  size_t size;
  char path[1024];  //current working directory path
  char ** files;    //created to store the directory contents in an array of strings
  char buffer ;     //buffer holds menu selection
  time_t rawtime;


  //buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
  files = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)+1);

  //allocating memory for strings
  for(i=0;i<50;i++)
  {
    files[i] =(char*) malloc(64*sizeof(char));
  }

  getcwd(path,size);

  pid_t child;
  DIR * d;
  struct dirent *de;

  d = opendir(".");

  i=0;

  while((de = readdir(d)))
  {
    files[i] = de->d_name;
    i++;
  }


  directSize = i;
  closedir(d);

  printf("file[0]: %s",files[0]);

  while(flag == 0)
  {
    printf("\nfiles[0]: %s\n",files[0]);    //works 

    printf("Current Working directory: %s\n", path);
    printf("\nfiles[0]: %s\nSize: %d\n",files[0],directSize);   //works

    time(&rawtime);
    printf("It is now: %s\n\n",ctime(&rawtime)); //problem area? 

    printf("files[0]: %s\nSize: %d\n",files[0],directSize);     //doesn't work
    printf("Files:\t\t0. (..)\n");

    for(i=start;i<start+4;i++)
      printf("\t\t%d. %s \n",i+1, files[i]);

    //formatted print for the command menu 
    printf("\nOperation:\tV View\n\t\tR Run\n\t\tP Previous Files\tN Next Files\n\t\tX Exit\t\t\tH Help\n");

    printf("\nCommand: ");
    scanf("%c", &buffer);
    getchar();
    //if(isalpha(buffer))
    //  strcpy(buffer,toupper(buffer));
    printf("command chosen is: %c\n",buffer);

    //if(buffer != "N" && buffer != "P" && buffer != "X")
    //{
    //  printf("File/Directory #: ");
    //  scanf("%d", &menu);
    //}

    if(buffer == 'E' || buffer == 'e')
      flag=flag+ 1; 

  }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How large of an array do you think that you created with the initial `malloc` (`(char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)+1)`)? Chances are, you are actually hitting a buffer overflow on the heap.

Comment: I actually increased the print out and it looks like they are there, but somehow their pointers have been reassigned... I still don't understand how simply calling the time messes this up though.  If I remove the call to print the time the problem goes away and everything is back the way it was.

Comment: I believe that you're looking at the wrong issue. I think that the time problems are a symptom of your buffer overflow. Your `files` array is almost certainly not as large as you believe it is; print out the value of `sizeof(char*) + 1`; you will almost certainly find that it's not `50`.

Comment: Valgrind time?  In my experience, Valgrind usually finds these kinds of issues.

Comment: If you want to allocate room for 50 pointers, it should be `malloc(50*sizeof(char*))`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you did not a deep copy of string.

```
 while((de = readdir(d)))
  {
    files[i] = de->d_name;   /* you just made files[i] pointing to de->d_name, instead of
                              * copy the content to files[i].
                              */
    i++;
  }
```

So after `closedir()`, the `libc` will reuse the inner buffer, the content may be modified by other function of `libc`, then you got a rubbish content.Replacing it with `strcpy(files[i], de->d_name)`.